# Trying to make the login system work

Tags: javascript, php, html

Using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ueruxlD0Smo&index=6&list=PLE134D877783367C7

I have tried to make a login system, the problem is, he has his login on his main page. So he made it when you click login it re-directs to login.php, but I have a login page, so I dont know how to make it check the database, then login and send to the main page. here is my code..

```
    <?php 
$pagetTitle = "Corvex | Logon";
$pageID = 2;
include 'include/header.php'; 

include 'core/init.php';


if(empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    echo $username, ' ', $password;
}
?>

<style>
.form-signin {
    max-width: 330px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<form>
  <h1>Employer Log in</h1>
  <div class="inset">
  <p>
    Username
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </p>
  <p>
    Password
    <input type="password" name="password">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember">
    <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
  </p>
  </div>
  <p class="p-container">
    <span><a href="http://www.google.com"> Forgot Password </a></span>
    <input type="submit" name="go" id="go" value="Log in">
  </p>
</form>

<?php include 'include/footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: What login system? There's just some html/form code there.

Comment: add more details to your question don't expect someone to watch that video  to help you. Please mention what he did in video and what are you trying to do

Comment: Well the database has a username/password in it, and here I am just checking to see if it can read it. Which is the If statement in the PHP code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when the HTML form gets posted you need to check the $_POST for the dictionary of values necessary to input in the database. The 'name' attribute in HTMl is what the key will be in the `$_POST` dictionary.

You need to change `<form>` to `<form action="login.php" method="POST">` so that the data is sent to the right page. Them at the top you are already checking the values to see if they are set.

You should reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php to look at functions necessary to communicate with MySQL to submit this data.